# Azure Functions Mac - Wrong Host Version

Tags: c#, azure-functions, visual-studio-mac

I am trying to debug an Azure functions project on my Mac using Visual Studio Mac.

I have updated my core tools to version 2.0.3. If I type `func` at my terminal, I can see I updated to the latest version.

```
                  %%%%%%
                 %%%%%%
            @   %%%%%%    @
          @@   %%%%%%      @@
       @@@    %%%%%%%%%%%    @@@
     @@      %%%%%%%%%%        @@
       @@         %%%%       @@
         @@      %%%       @@
           @@    %%      @@
                %%
                %

Azure Functions Core Tools (2.0.3)
Function Runtime Version: 2.0.12115.0
```

You can also see the runtime version is `2.0.12115.0`.

However when I debug using Visual Studio Mac, I get a runtime error:

> Hosting environment: Production Now listening on: http://0.0.0.0:7071
>   Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down. [09/10/2018 20:30:53]
>   Reading host configuration file
>   'xxxxx/bin/Debug/netstandard2.0/host.json' [09/10/2018 20:30:53] Host
>   configuration file read: [09/10/2018 20:30:53] {} [09/10/2018
>   20:30:53] Starting Host (HostId=xxxxx,
>   InstanceId=0ef8b0eb-215d-4d08-9945-6dd50c8094c7, Version=2.0.11933.0,
>   ProcessId=22941, AppDomainId=1, Debug=False, ConsecutiveErrors=0,
>   StartupCount=1, FunctionsExtensionVersion=) Function host is not
>   running. Press any to continue....[09/10/2018 20:30:58] A ScriptHost
>   error has occurred [09/10/2018 20:30:58] System.Private.CoreLib: Could
>   not load type 'Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Hosting.IWebJobsStartup' from
>   assembly 'Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host, Version=3.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.

Notice the runtime version is `Version=2.0.11933.0`.

There must be a way to tell visual studio where the location of the Azure-Functions-Core tools is installed or can I at least copy my 2.0.3 installation to where Visual Studio is executing from, where ever that is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Visual Studio for Mac currently needs to be updated for every Functions CLI release. It unfortunately does not support being configured with a version of the Functions CLI installed on the machine (and this has been problematic for a lot of people).

The next VS Mac update should reference the latest Functions CLI and I believe an update is planned to allow it to independently update the version of the CLI it uses without requiring a full VS update.

Comment: Ok, that's sort of what I read between the lines in that I was expecting an update to fix the issue. Seem strange that 2.0.3 was released 20 days ago and a new version on Visual Studio Mac was released on the Beta channel just a few days ago claiming to have better Azure Function Support in the readme. But it still did not resolve the issue.  I'll wait a bit longer and see.

Answer (score 0):

Note for anyone else experiencing this, I have just downloaded on the `Beta Channel` the latest version of Visual Studio for Mac

> Version **7.7** Build **1738**

And this now supports the latest version of the core tools and works correctly!